# Find multiple substrings from a column entry in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2, db2-luw

I have a Table like this

```
|   ID   |  otherID  | Data
+--------+-----------+----------------
|  1234  |   56789   | This is a Name: Charlie; string <name_starts> with Name: Alpha; also some more data and Name: Bravo;
```

here the last column has a string and I need those names from it (there could be many Names), so the output should look like this

```
|   Name   
+------------------
|  Alpha;Bravo;
```

I wrote the following query that can retrieve the first name, but I need all the names and it is not known how many names are there

```
select substr(Data, locate('Name',Data)+6, locate(':',Data)-locate(':',Data)-6) from myTable
```

EDIT: Sorry I missed a point that I have to take all the names that occur after "name_starts", before that if there are any I need to ignore them. So sorry about missing this while posting.

Also, I'm using DB2-LUW v9.7

Comment: I don't know db2, but in ms sql or oracle I would write a stored procedure or function that does this. you basically want to perform you substr in a loop until it returns an empty string. You could also split the string into an array and loop through that, depending on what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately I have DB2 10.5 only. I think you can get the result you want by using a recursive CTE and combining REGEXP_COUNT() with REGEXP_EXTRACT(), available in 11.1.

Comment: Hello manish, can you explain how do you detect a name ? It is the string between 'Name: ' and ';' (included) ! If so, have you try using Regex if possible on DB2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have 10.5 at hand, but it works on 11.1:

```
WITH TAB (DATA) AS 
(
VALUES
  'This is a string with Name: Alpha; also some more data and Name: Bravo;'
)
SELECT 
--REGEXP_REPLACE(T.DATA, '.*? Name: ([^\s]+)', '$1') -- Since 11.1
xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:replace($s, ".*? Name: ([^\s]+)", "$1")' passing T.DATA as "s") as varchar(100))
FROM TAB T;
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks it works but it does not remove the extra string that is after the last Name.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

> ```
> with data (s) as (values ('This is a string with Name: Alpha; also some more data and Name: Bravo;'))
> select listagg(regexp_substr(s,'(?<=Name\: )[A-Za-z]+(?=\;)', 1, n),';')
> from   data
> cross  join (values (1),(2)) x (n)
> where  n <= regexp_count(s,'(?<=Name\: )[A-Za-z]+(?=\;)')
> ```

Comment: regexp is not supported

Comment: What's your exact Db2 platform and version?

Comment: Hi Mark, I am using DB2 - LUW v9.7